# Join multiple databases in one View -- SQL Server Mangement Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, view, cross-database

I would like to join fields from two different databases that reside on the same server, but I am having trouble with the syntax.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your user has privileges in both databases, just reference the "remote" object using three part naming:

```
SELECT columns
FROM database2.dbo.table
```